# CSS3 DIVs different backgrounds

Tags: css

I am a CSS3 noob, just getting started by using different web examples so please excuse me if this question is silly or too basic (we all have to learn sometime!)

I have a simple example DIV and it's styled like this:

```
.img1 {
    width:206px;
    height:206px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:url(Mom206x206.jpg);

}
```

Two questions:

1 - is this legal syntax `background:url(Mom206x206.jpg)` or shouldn't it be with quotes: `background:url("Mom206x206.jpg")`

2 - How do I use the same class but have different backgrounds?
Or will I have to make a different class for every background I want in this style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- The documentation on [URLs and URIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri) states that:

> The format of a URI value is 'url(' followed by optional white space
>   followed by an optional single quote (') or double quote (") character
>   followed by the URI itself, followed by an optional single quote (')
>   or double quote (") character followed by optional white space
>   followed by ')'. The two quote characters must be the same.

So, the following three are valid:

```
background:url(Mom206x206.jpg)
background:url('Mom206x206.jpg')
background:url("Mom206x206.jpg")
```

2.- You can use a class to set common properties and individual classes for individual backgrounds:

```
/* Common styles */
.img {
    width:206px;
    height:206px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Individual styles */
.img.bg1 { background:url(bg1.jpg); }
.img.bg2 { background:url(bg2.jpg); }
.img.bg3 { background:url(bg3.jpg); }
.img.bg4 { background:url(bg4.jpg); }
.img.bg5 { background:url(bg5.jpg); }
```

Now you can have your HTML like this:

```
<div class="img bg1">DIV With background 1</div>
<div class="img bg2">DIV With background 2</div>
<div class="img bg3">DIV With background 3</div>
<div class="img bg4">DIV With background 4</div>
<div class="img bg5">DIV With background 5</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the image file in the same directory as your CSS?

Comment: Got it working :) You missed a dot at the beginning of img.bg1 :) like this `.img.bg1`

Comment: It's all good, I learned something new by finding the error that is unlikely to be forgotten soon :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, in quote. For example: `background: #00ff00 url('Mom206x206.jpg')`
2. Different class would be cleaner

Comment: 1 - you have just one single quote there.  So if I have 200 boxes with background images, I should have 200 classes? :(   Is there any other solution to that?